# Can't get Twitterlib fetchtweets() to return queries from a list

Tags: javascript, twitter, google-apps-script, twitter-search

first time here and just started investigating Twitter bots to retweet traffic info to my followers. Am using Amit Agarwal's labnol bot on Google Script and have changed very little (removed favoriting tweets) but I cannot get it to retweet anything using my search parameters despite there being matching tweets on Twitter, could someone check what I'm doing wrong, I don't know enough (yet) to spot the problem? Thanks in advance.

```
// Written by Amit Agarwal @labnol on 31/07/2015

// Fill the Twitter Keys and then choose Run -> Start Bot

TWITTER_CONSUMER_KEY    = "removed";
TWITTER_CONSUMER_SECRET = "removed";
TWITTER_ACCESS_TOKEN    = "removed";
TWITTER_ACCESS_SECRET   = "removed";
TWITTER_SEARCH_PHRASE   = 'A13 list:a13essex/traffic';

function Start_Bot() {

  var props = PropertiesService.getScriptProperties();

  props.setProperties({
    TWITTER_CONSUMER_KEY: TWITTER_CONSUMER_KEY,
    TWITTER_CONSUMER_SECRET: TWITTER_CONSUMER_SECRET,
    TWITTER_ACCESS_TOKEN: TWITTER_ACCESS_TOKEN,
    TWITTER_ACCESS_SECRET: TWITTER_ACCESS_SECRET,
    SINCE_TWITTER_ID: 0
  });

  var twit = new Twitter.OAuth(props);

  // Test Twitter authorization

  if (!twit.favorite("628053456071192576")) {
    throw new Error("Please check your Twitter access tokens");
    return;
  }

  ScriptApp.newTrigger("labnol_twitterBot")
  .timeBased()
  .everyMinutes(10)
  .create();

}

function labnol_twitterBot() {

  try {

    var props = PropertiesService.getScriptProperties(),
        twit = new Twitter.OAuth(props);

    if (twit.hasAccess()) {

      var tweets = twit.fetchTweets(
        TWITTER_SEARCH_PHRASE, function(tweet) {
          // Skip tweets that contain sensitive content
          if (!tweet.possibly_sensitive) {
            return tweet.id_str;
          }
        }, {
          multi: true,
          lang: "en", // Process only English tweets
          count: 5,   // Process 5 tweets in a batch
          since_id: props.getProperty("SINCE_TWITTER_ID")
        });

      if (tweets) {

        props.setProperty("SINCE_TWITTER_ID", tweets[0]);

        for (var i = tweets.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {

          twit.retweet(tweets[i]);

          /* Wait between 10 seconds and 1 minute */
          Utilities.sleep(Math.floor(Math.random()*50000) + 10000);

        }
      }
    }

  } catch (f) {
    Logger.log("Error: " + f.toString());
  }

}

// Email: amit@labnol.org
// Premium Support: http://ctrlq.org
```

This returns the following result in the log:

```
[16-09-30 11:25:32:289 BST] https://api.twitter.com/1.1/search/tweets.json?lang=en&count=5&since_id=undefined&include_entities=false&result_type=recent&q=A13%20list%3Aa13essex%252Ftraffic
[16-09-30 11:25:32:292 BST] lang=en
[16-09-30 11:25:32:293 BST] count=5
[16-09-30 11:25:32:293 BST] since_id=undefined
[16-09-30 11:25:32:294 BST] include_entities=false
[16-09-30 11:25:32:294 BST] result_type=recent
[16-09-30 11:25:32:295 BST] q=A13 list:a13essex%2Ftraffic
[16-09-30 11:25:32:375 BST] No matching tweets this go-round
```

Is https://api.twitter.com/1.1/search/tweets.json?lang=en&count=5&since_id=undefined&include_entities=false&result_type=recent&q=A13%20list%3Aa13essex%252Ftraffic correct? Thanks again, Paul

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've identified another special character encoding issue with fetchTweets.  I did some API checks and the encoding of slash should be %2F on the URL to return the proper result set.

I've filed an issue on Github for the next release:  https://github.com/airhadoken/twitter-lib/issues/16

In the meantime you can use `twit.fetch("https://api.twitter.com/1.1/search/tweets.json?lang=en&count=5&since_id=undefined&include_entities=false&result_type=recent&q=A13%20list%3Aa13essex%2Ftraffic")` as a workaround; you will have to `JSON.parse` the content text to get the tweets as objects.  I'll report back when you can use `fetchTweets()` again (i.e. when Twitter lib v23 is ready to release).

Thanks for letting me know!
-- Bradley Momberger, creator/maintainer of Twitter lib.

Comment: I was considering contacting you, @air_hadoken as that was my first thought when I saw the log but I wasn't confident enough to come out and say it! I'm already using a similar workaround, just can't get it to call and set since_id but as I said I'm just starting out so still trying to suss it out. Glad it helped though

Comment: You should be able to just append `"&since_id=" + props.getProperty("SINCE_TWITTER_ID")` to the end of the URL when fetching.  Don't forget to store `id_str` of the last tweet into `props`.

Comment: Thanks, I'd already done this and was actually having trouble storing the info but I sorted it in the end although more by luck than judgement!

Comment: FYI, a new version of Twitter lib is out (v23).  If you upgrade, those queries should work with fetchTweets() now.

Comment: Thanks for remembering to come back to let me know. The workaround is still working well so will stick with that but should it fail I'll switch to yours.